# Function is producing NA's in rbinom

Tags: r, na

Im trying to generate a ROC curve using the code I generated but unfortunately Im running into an error around my second for loop with the message "Warning in rbinom(n = n.rep, size = nw, prob = pw) : NAS produced
Error in fisher.test(comparison, alternative = "two.sided") : all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite"

Im not sure how to fix it as Im trying to generate a plot similar to https://www.google.com/search?q=roc+curve&sxsrf=ALiCzsa7CDz2M4T966xTaEEY4PdVjSS_oA:1652663488010&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-gYuh6-L3AhUXlXIEHfRaBcEQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1536&bih=713&dpr=2.5#imgrc=6aCqP2X4Iz8EWM.

```
n.rep = 1000
power = numeric()

powerCalc = function(nc, pc, nw, pw) {
  control <- rbinom(n=n.rep, size = nc, prob = pc)
  c.diff <- nc - (control)
  wasps <- rbinom(n=n.rep, size = nw, prob = pw)
  w.diff <- nw - (wasps)
  
  fisher <- vector()
  for (i in 1:n.rep){
    comparison <- matrix(c(control[i],c.diff[i], wasps[i], w.diff[i]), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
    fisher[i] <- fisher.test(comparison, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value
  }
  power = sum(fisher < alpha)/1000
  return(power)
}

nc = 50
pc = 0.2
nw = 50
pw = 0.5

hell = vector()
i=1
for (alpha in seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.01)) {
  hell[i] = powerCalc(nc,pc,nw,pw)
  i = i+1
}

plot(seq(from=0, to=1, length.out=0.01), hell, type = "l")
```

Comment: I've seen rbinom() throw this error when size (2nd parameter) is not an integer as well, but I suspect prob = 50 is the problem too.

Comment: @JohnGarland Thanks I fixed that to 0.5 and that fixed that error but now its showing Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Comment: Change `length.out = 0.01` to `by = 0.01` in your `plot(seq())`.

Comment: Better practice: define `alpha` one time instead of repeating the definition and introducing typos, or making if you change it making you need to change it in multiple places. `alpha = seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.01)` before the loop, `for(i in seq_along(alpha))` to set the loop, delete `i = i + 1` because it's no longer needed, but probably you should use `alpha[i]` somewhere inside the loop (it's weird that you don't... you're just repeating the same calculation 101 times), and your plot becomes more readable `plot(alpha, hell, type = "l")`.